# Opencart 3 New Linux Server File Manager Problems

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I recently moved to a new server & installed Opencart v3. I've had problems with only 3 versions. Although I've been trying to installing it several times, it does not work. I have a theme for v3 and I must install it.

This is for a new Linux server, running Centos 7.

Screenshots:

*Admin Dashboard*

https://ibb.co/n8Jqw6T

*Image Uploader*

https://ibb.co/pwYpfzG

Comment: Screenshoots:
https://ibb.co/pwYpfzG
https://ibb.co/n8Jqw6T

Comment: Your post does not describe which problem you experienced with your Opencart setup. Please avoid referencing screenshots. The links may become invalid after some time because the hoster wipes files contents. It is better to include the error message text with post. Sometime it is also helpful to describe the installation steps performed. If you followed strictly the step installation guide, you can simply state this with (possibly) a reference to installation guide used.

Comment: Regarding the error "Invalid token session. Please login again." there are several topics on Opencart User Forum dealing with the matter. For example, https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=201029 https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=204066

Comment: Please upload the images using StackOverflow, they can be attached to the post directly. This ensures people can see them .(For example, `ibb.co` is blocked for me.)